D&D 5e Paladin Warlock build
I have 20 levels to build a Spear/Shield badarse who at level 3 has:
STR 16 DEX 14 CON 18 INT 14 WIS 14 CHA 18 (Provided by DM).
We are heavy Roleplayers.
I wish to build a 7’ air Genasi who fights like an air demon pulling out the deadliest single target combat that I can.
We fight lots of mobs at a time but few at a time in fights.
I’ve read pally 6 lock 4 (this next bit I love but need solid advice): Ranger (Gloomstalker) 4 (feat) Fighter 6.
Focus of build: Destroy someone in single combat with Paladin/Warlock as base. Please spell it out out for me.
Disclaimer: I am a disabled Vet, I only say this because I don’t sometimes “get” things.  If you are good enough to take time and post, know I appreciate it very much.

Hi, and welcome to the stack! A detail that can have a surprising amount of impact on this nowadays is what world/backgrounds are allowed in your campaign, since some of them come with feats or features that can drastically alter spell access, even for purely martial characters. Subclasses allowed, as well.

When you say destroy someone in single combat, do you mean destroy one of the targets in the combat alongside your party, or win a 1v1 combat?

To tag onto @DavidCoffron 's excellent question, I'd also ask, in the case of 1v1 combat, do you mean versus NPC's or other PC's? They are very different ballparks of answer, and it's worth noting that a CR 3 encounter is typically meant for a party of level 3 characters, not a single one. That doesn't make it impossible, but does provide some scope to the question and the setting.

When you say you have 20 levels, are you asking for a level by level progression, or just a level 20 build?

Don't sweat it
The fact of the matter is that PCs at high levels are pretty much too strong for the monsters as written, if you follow the CR guidelines. Our DM regularly confronts us with encounters that are multiple times the recommended "deadly" encounter value, and we still survive them. That means you do not need to hyper-optimize to have an awesome, powerful PC, and can focus on roleplaying your character.
That said, here are a few hints, based on the experience of having a player in our group that regularly plays Paladin/Warlock characters.

Hexblade is a useful warlock subclass, to keep with the theme of melee combat abilities. This gives access to the shield spell, which when combined with the armor can get you ridiculously high AC when it matters; Green Flame Blade, if available, can also be a useful cantrip for melee, and Hexblade's Curse is a good use for your bonus action.
Oath of Vengeance is a good option for combat damage if you want to do 6 levels of paladin.
A useful trick that can make you very hard to beat in 1:1 combat (or any combat, really) is to pick up the darkness spell and Devil's Sight from the warlock. That means you can see, and most of your opponents cannot see in magical darkness, granting you both advantage to your attacks, and disadvantage to theirs, which, combined with high AC makes you nearly impossible to hit. (This may appear redundant with your Umbral Sight invisibility, but it works more reliably, and in combination guarantees dark environs, so even for those that can see in magical darkness, you will be invisible).

Other than that, the class distribution looks reasonable, trying to get you as many feats as you can while heavily multiclassing. I‘m not sure you need to throw in Gloomstalker Ranger, but you also have decent Wisdom, and perma-invisibility in dark environments is very strong, as is the ini boost and extra ambush attack, so why not. If you only took 3 levels of warlock, and no gloom stalker, you could take 11 levels of Fighter and get consistent 2 extra attacks every round of combat. It might also play a bit simpler, depending on what fighter subclass you pick. Either way works.

Or just stick with Paladin/ Sorcerer for the spell slots to fuel divine strike and, well, for the spells :)

Minor note: When you say "This may appear redundant with your Umbral Sight invisibility, but it works more reliably, and in combination guarantees dark environs, so even for those that can see in magical darkness, you will be invisible", while that is true for most (all?) monsters with Devil's Sight (which is phrased in terms of their darkvision working in magical darkness as well), other Warlocks with the Devil's Sight invocation would not have an issue with Umbral Sight invisibility, because it's not phrased in terms of darkvision at all, they just "see normally in darkness".

@ShadowRanger interesting point, but no published creatures have the Warlock's Devil's Sight invocation, so this would only matter in the case the DM homebrews a Warlock PC enemy for the players to interact with that didn't have darkvision to begin with, or perhaps with other Warlocks in the party, but for them, that would be a benefit.
